# Let $(X,d)$ a metric space. Prove if $x \in X$ and $r>0$ then $B(x,r)$ is a open set

Tags: real-analysis

Good morning! I need help with this problem.

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space. Prove if $x \in X$ and $r>0$ then $B(x,r)$ is a open set

**Proof**

> We need to prove this:
>    **$\forall a \in X \exists r_1>0$ such that $B(a,r_1)\subset B(x,r)$**  
>   
>   
>   Suppose $r_1=\frac{1}{2}$$min(d(a,x),r-d(a,x))$ 
>   Let $y \in B(a,r_1)$ then $d(a.y)<r_1$
>   
> Besides, $r>r_1$ by the form of $r_1$. 
>   Then we have: $d(a,y)<r_1<r$ 
>   
> Then $d(a,y)<r$. 
>   
> That implies: $y\in B(a,r)$
>   
>  in particular this happen for $a=x$, then $y\in B(x,r)$.
>   That conclude the proof.

I don't sure of my proof, can some help me with the review of the proof, of one hint for this problem?

Comment: What's your definition of open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is for the most part correct.
But the last two lines are not what you want. Since you have just showed that there is an $r_1$ for $a=x$ but not for all $a\in B(x,r)$.
You need to show that $d(x,y)<r$ and your choice of $r_1$ ensures that:

$$d(x,y)\leq d(x,a)+d(a,y)<d(x,a)+ \frac12(r-d(a,x))<r. $$

I suggest you streamline the proof a little bit.

Suppose $a\in B(x,r)$. Choose $r_1=r-d(x,a)$. Then for all $y\in B(a,r_1)$
$$d(x,y)\leq d(x,a)+d(a,y)<d(x,a)+ (r-d(a,x))=r. $$
Hence $B(a,r_1)\subseteq B(x,r)$.

Answer (score 1):

With your choice of $r_1$, it's possible for $r_1 = 0$, namely, when $a = x$. Instead, set $r_1 = r - d(a,x)$ so that $r_1 > 0$. Use the triangle inequality to show that $d(y,x) < r$ whenever $d(y,a) < r_1$.