# Let $A$ a open set, and let $x \in A$. Prove $A -${$x$} is open.

Tags: real-analysis

Good morning, i have a problem with this exercise: 
***Problem:*** **Let $A$ a open set, and let $x \in A$. Prove $A -${$x$} is open.**

 **My Proof:**

> We need to show for all $a\in X$ exist $r>0$ such that $B(a,r) \subset A -${$x$}.
>   Let $y\in B(a,r)$ for all $a \in X$ and $r>0$, and $y \not = x$. We know $A$ is open, then for all $c \in X$ exist $r_1>0$ such that $B(c,r_1)\subset A$.
>   
>   For this result: [Let $(X,d)$ a metric space. Prove if $x \in X$ and $r>0$ then $B(x,r)$ is a open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447682/let-x-d-a-metric-space-prove-if-x-in-x-and-r0-then-bx-r-is-a-open/2447709#2447709) we have $B(a,r)\subset B(x,r_1)\subset A$
>   
>  Then $y \in A-${$x$}
>   We concludes this: $B(a,r) \subset A -${$x$} then $A -${$x$} is open.

I don't know if the proof if fine. Can someone help me with that? or give me some tips for solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Jack My definition of open is for all $a \in X$ and $r>0$ $B(a,r) \in A$, then $A$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

In your whole space $X$, the singleton set $\{x\}$ is a closed set.  The complement $X - \{x\}$ is open since it is the complement of the closed set $\{x\}$.  If $A$ is open in $X$ then $A \cap (X - \{x\})$ is an intersection of two open sets in $X$, and is therefore open.   If $x \in A$ then this is the same as $A - \{x\}$.

Comment: the singleton set $\{x\}$ is a closed set, because $X- \{x\}$ is open set, is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the definition of open set as one that contains a ball around each of its points, your ideas are in the right direction, but not well expressed.

Consider $y\in A-\{x\}$.

Then there exists a ball $B(y,r)$ such that $B(y,r)\subset A$, since $A$ is open. Let $r'=\min\{r,d(x,y)/2)$. Then $r'>0$ (because $d(x,y)>0$); moreover
$$
B(y,r')\subset B(y,r) \subset A
$$
and $x\notin B(y,r')$, so we conclude that
$$
B(y,r')\subset A-\{x\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $\{x\}$ is closed.

I think now it's clear.

Comment: I dont, understand... can you be more specific?

Comment: @Bvss12 In a metric space, all singletons are closed, hence $\{x\}$ is closed and so $X-\{x\}$ is open. If $A$ and $X-\{x\}$ are open, then their intersection is open.

Comment: Thanks @KevinLong i dont know that!